# Artifact Removal from X-Ray Images

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'll have a lot of X-Ray images of trucks moving through a X-Ray scanner at the speed 40 km/h. The goal is to remove the truck per se from a scan and leave only cargo so that operators could easier detect threats and forbidden items in cargo.

My initial thought was to use neural networks to detect which truck among seen earlier is closest to one just being scanned. If the closest is still far-away, I'd add this current one to 'seen before' as a new. If not, subtract from the scan of the current truck the most similar truck so we get only cargo as a result. One problem is that it's not clear yet how to remove cargo from a truck just added to the model. In addition, there are too many types of truck, so performance may be unsatisfactory.

Would ideas on how to solve this task would you suggest? Or on what resource on the internet can I find help?

Comment: This is an open area of research.. the question is too broad. Finding something that works for your images and your application would take weeks/months to design.

Answer (score 0):

This is a too broad question so unfortunately I have to just share an idea:

Try to solve the binary classification task for each of image *pixels*, classifying it as 'part of cargo'\'not part of cargo'. I believe by using deep convolution nets with pooling layers you should be able to get a system which will tell you which pixels represent the cargo in image and which represent a truck.